# Can you use the login system of a website in your website

Tags: html

I have a question regarding the login system. So let’s say that I’m building a website that requires from the users to login but I don’t want them to create an account only for my website. What I want to do instead is to log them in if they have an account to (let’s say ) the website X.

In short I want to use the login system of a second website X for users to enter my website. Is that possible in any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use oauth if *the website X* implements it.

OAuth is an open standard for access delegation, commonly used as a way for Internet users to grant websites or applications access to their information on other websites but without giving them the passwords.

Facebook, google and others let you log in with their systems through oauth.